# PyDTMC output graph overlaps on code in a notebook

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, markov-chains

I just installed PyDTMC and use it in a Jupyter notebook.
Following the examples on this page https://pypi.org/project/PyDTMC/ leads to a surprising result: plot_graph() overlaps on code above.

How could I fix that?

(m.plot_graph(mc, dpi=200) shows the full graph, but I don't like this workaround)

Note: jupyter-notebook 6.3.0, Python 3.8.5, PyDTMC 4.9.0 (on Archlinux)

[image]

Comment: The source code being not very complicated https://github.com/TommasoBelluzzo/PyDTMC/blob/master/pydtmc/plotting.py , an option would be to edit it. But there may be an easier way :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was mentioned here https://github.com/TommasoBelluzzo/PyDTMC/issues/6 with a fixing suggestion. Fix applied in this fork https://github.com/yagu0/PyDTMC.

It's still unclear why the figure size needs to be augmented (setting a higher dpi also works, but doesn't look like a clean solution). So I let this post open, in case of someone could explain :-)